# mysql And javascript Clone form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How do i add amount without storing it in the database.
For example an input with amount of 50 (this value is executed from the database) and after cloning the form and insert 50 the amount will add up and display 100

this is my form

```
</form>
<form action="form/getinfo.php" method="post" id="adres">
<div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
<h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Adres 1</h2>
<fieldset>
<label class="label_ln" for="last_name">Amount</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="50" value="">
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?